# How to upload folders to GCS from node js using client library

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage

To upload files to google-cloud-storage (gcs) from node there is documented process like

```
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
{
const bucket = storage.bucket("bt-name");
const res = await bucket.upload("./output_images/dir/file.png", {
            public: true
        });
}
```

But I want to upload entire **dir** to gcs in said bucket **bt-name**, when I try to do so it throws promise rejection error -- *EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a built-in feature to upload a whole folder using the API or client library. If you would like to upload the whole folder, you would need your code to iterate through all the folder files in a loop and upload all of them one at a time, or you could use the recursive upload option with the command-line utility [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp).

Comment: Yeah, there seems to be no other way.. So for now uploading one by one, as can't use gsutil. Thanx